# Reload secondary combobox array on primary combobox change event

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

Here is my code to add a combobox array to a groupbox array and then when an item in the combo box is selected it displays a secondary combobox

```
Dim gbQuoteProduct(5) As GroupBox
Dim cmboBoxQuoteProduct(5) As ComboBox
gbQuoteProduct(n) = New GroupBox

Private Sub frmCreateQuote_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
With gbQuoteProduct(n)
    .Text = ""
    .Location = New Point(10, 5 + n * 70)
    .Width = 300
    .Height = 70
End With
pnlQuoteProducts.Controls.Add(gbQuoteProduct(n))

cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n) = New ComboBox
With cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n)
    .Items.Add("A")
    .Items.Add("B")
    .Items.Add("C")
    .Items.Add("D")
    .Text = ""
    .Location = New Point(60, 15)
End With
gbQuoteProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n))
AddHandler cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf subProducts
End Sub
```

Where "subproducts" just generates a secondary combobox.

But if I select the wrong option from the first combobox and then try to change my selection, the secondary combobox doesn't refresh the new combobox. In other words, the options of the second combobox don't change to reflect the change in the first combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and succeed. The code is below the image
[image: Dynamic ComboBox Management]

```
Public Class frmQuestion28955485
    Dim gbQuoteProduct(5) As GroupBox
    Dim cmboBoxQuoteProduct(5) As ComboBox

    Dim cmboBoxSubProducts(5) As ComboBox
    Dim n As Integer

    Private Sub frmCreateQuote_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        n = 1
        gbQuoteProduct(n) = New GroupBox
        With gbQuoteProduct(n)
            .Text = ""
            .Location = New Point(10, 5 + n * 70)
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 70
        End With
        pnlQuoteProducts.Controls.Add(gbQuoteProduct(n))

        cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n) = New ComboBox
        With cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n)
            .Items.Add("A")
            .Items.Add("B")
            .Items.Add("C")
            .Items.Add("D")
            .Text = ""
            .Location = New Point(60, 15)
        End With
        gbQuoteProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n))
        AddHandler cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf subProducts
    End Sub
    Private Sub subProducts(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            gbQuoteProduct(n).Controls.Remove(cmboBoxSubProducts(n))
        Catch

        End Try

        cmboBoxSubProducts(n) = New ComboBox
        With cmboBoxSubProducts(n)
            .Items.Clear()
            .Items.Add("You picked " + cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n).Text)
            .Text = "You picked " + cmboBoxQuoteProduct(n).Text
            .Location = New Point(60, 40)
        End With
        gbQuoteProduct(n).Controls.Add(cmboBoxSubProducts(n))
    End Sub
End Class
```